# Why is setx path not working?

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables

Can someone explain this result?

After setting path, it did not change. This was run in an Administrator command-line:

```
C:\Windows\system32>setx path "C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin"

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

C:\Windows\system32>path
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\metapad36;D:\Program Files (x86)\metapad36" /M
```

I've read that %PATH% = PATH variable for machine + PATH variable for user. Am I seeing the machine path + Admin's path?

Have looked at other articles on the topic, but still confused.

Should I clear the user paths, so there's no duplication?

**update**: Re the tip that "variables created or modified by this tool will be available in future command windows" i open a **non-admin** window and enter:

```
>path
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;;D:\Program Files (x86)\metapad36;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

The path is repeated twice. Ok, then at same prompt I `setx` the path without the repeat, and without `/M`:

```
>setx path "C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin"

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
```

Apparently saved in current user environment.

Then i open a ***new*** **non-admin** command window, and:

```
>path
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;;D:\Program Files (x86)\metapad36;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin`
```

It has not changed. Why?

Comment: If the "duplication" comes from the system variable, you'll need to `setx /M` the corrected `path` too (at an elevated cmd prompt, of course). Changing the user value of `path` is not going to _remove_ entries that are defined in the system value of `path`.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that `path` entered on a **non-Admin** command-line returns system-wide path, not *user-level* path. Really? I notice entering `path` entered on a **non-Admin** command-line returns different results than `path` entered on an **Admin** command-line. But if both cases return system-path, why are they different? thx

Comment: No, you misunderstood. You only need the elevated prompt in order for `setx /M` to be allowed to change the system environment variable `path`. Other than that, the elevated (run-as-admin) and regular (non-elevated) cmd prompts have the same environment. Note that `PATH` in particular is a combination of system PATH + user PATH, see for example [Environment variables in Windows NT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/100843): `The User path is appended to the system path.` If you somehow set both to the same value, the resulting PATH will contain duplicates like you are seeing.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Windows, each process gets a copy of the environment which is essentially a snapshot of the global environment at the time the process was started. Changes to the global environment *while* the process is running are not propagated back to the process' own copy of the environment.

To answer the actual question, `setx` does modify the user environment (or the system one if run with `/M`), but the changes are not immediately visible in the process that executed `setx`, in this case `cmd.exe`. If you open a *new* command prompt after running `setx`, you'll see the changes in *that* instance of `cmd.exe`.

This is explicitly noted in the `setx /?` help:

> On a local system, variables created or modified by this tool will be available in future command windows but not in the current CMD.exe command window.

To effect the same changes in *both* the global environment, and the one of the current process, you need to run *both* `setx` and`set`.

Comment: I have a similar case, but in Set Environment Variables, in shells run as Administrator and in registry (both current user and system-wide variables) PATH is ok, because I set it this way in the registry editor. Even after reboot though `$Env:PATH` or `echo %path%` show path with duplicates. `Setx` executes successfully but nothing changes for subsequent instances of shells, `set` only changes PATH for current shell session. How do I get my PATHs in sync?

Comment: @Yar That's hard to guess without any details. First thing to check would be the user and machine environments after each change, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1179433/how-to-list-global-environment-variables-separately-from-user-specific-environme) for example. If that doesn't match what you expect you should post a separate question with the exact steps to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Just an FYI for anyone finding this old post...

SETX (and most other programmatic methods via PowerShell, .Net, C#, etc.) only take immediate affect for new processes run by the user who runs SETX.  If SETX is run by a different user or by the System account (as most corp deployment products would), a reboot would still be required for any other user to receive the update.  Even closing Explorer.exe and re-running under the affected user won't refresh.

Microsoft is doing some programmatic magic to the shell environment(s) when you modify environment variables via the standard Windows GUI.

Answer (score 1):

At first, open your cmd as administrator user then runs setx command

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the setx command will in fact only reflect the changes in a next terminal session.

To immediately reflect in the same terminal you can simply change the value of the variable by assignment.

```bash
$env:VAR_test = "test value"
```

Ready.