# problem on read azure container and blob in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm learning Python and I wanna print the list of all my blob storage in Azure. Find the sample code from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/samples/blob_samples_enumerate_blobs.py).

I have done this step:

1. set connection string:[image]
2. After the run I received this error [image]

**Note: Like my experience, your problem solved after the restart.**

Comment: This problem solved with a restart VS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. Just restart your VS Code and run it again. It will work. You error cause by `setx` command. It can't work in the current command window. You can refer to [Why is setx path not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347451/why-is-setx-path-not-working/35352014)

> On a local system, variables created or modified by this tool will be
> available in future command windows but not in the current CMD.exe
> command window.